# How to format date from Firestore in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

Im trying to display dates from Firestore Database in BigQuery.

Here is an example of my Firestore Document

[image: Here is an example of my Firestore Document]

I would like to display this timestamp, "f58-sodleDate", in BigQuery as 2023-10-3.

In BigQuery Console, I wrote this code

```
json_extract(data, '$.f58-sodleDate'),
```

and I get this  {"_seconds":1691471596,"_nanoseconds":483000000}

And if I write this code,

```
parse_datetime("%c", JSON_VALUE(DATA, '$.f58-sodleDate')) as dte,

// or this code

JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(DATA, '$.f58-sodleDate') AS dte,
```

I get the query result as null, like this

[image: this query result]

And if I write this code

```
date(timestamp_seconds(cast(json_extract(data, '$.f58-sodleDate') as int64))) AS dte,
```

I get this error message

[image: error message]

What I want for my query result is something like this
[image: correct query result]

I achieved this by writing this code

```
FORMAT_DATE('%F', timestamp) as dte,
```

Please tell me what I have to do to achieve the result I want..

Thank you, best. - STW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after going through several Youtube videos and StackOverflow answers,
I have got the result I want by writing this line of code

```
EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST(PARSE_NUMERIC(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$.f56-daysOnZayyan._seconds'))* 1000 AS INT64))) AS dte,
```